# Implicit pattern matching the first 2 items of a list

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to do this in an implicit way:

`(originalPath:extractPath:ignoredArgs) <- getArgs`

considering I only need the first two args and will ignore the others anyway.

This is just a curiosity/exploring/learning question (just started with Haskell), `ignoredArgs` does not harm if it's left like this.

I tried

`(originalPath:extractPath) <- getArgs`

But it fails since `extractPath` will be of `[String]` type (instead of `String`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a wildcard, `_`

```
(originalPath:extractPath:_) <- getArgs
```

to ignore everything after the first two arguments.

You need to have something there to have the two names be bound to `String`s, and a wildcard pattern (underscore) is the way to tell the compiler and human readers of the code that you are not interested in further arguments.